# ¿Es posible agregar más de un `inlineImage` en `htmlbody`?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-html-service

Vengo aprendiendo a usar Apps Scripts y estoy realizando un módulo de envío de correos masivos. Tengo 2 archivos uno con código .gs y otro .html, el html es una plantilla de texto que recibirá cada dirección de correo.

**lo que quiero lograr hacer:**
La ultima imagen es un bosquejo de cómo se recibe el correo, he logrado con éxito las primeras 2 partes, header,body. **NO logro hacer el footer ya que la imagen no  carga**

la pregunta es:
**es posible agregar más de un `inlineImage` en `htmlbody`**

Si es así me podrían mostrar con código, el resultado final debe quedar como el bosquejo ya que así se me solicita el resultado. ¿ o  de qué otra manera que pueda cargar ambas imágenes en el `header` y `footer` del html?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El código se debe de agregar usando texto, no imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es posible agregar más de una imagen.

`inlineImages` es un objeto con una propiedad por cada una de las imágenes donde el nombre de la propiedad es la clave de la imagen usada la etiqueta `img` y el valor el es Blob de la imagen.

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options